# implementing open/write function for FAT file system

Tags: filesystems, fat32, fat, broadcom

I have to implement open/write function in the Broadcomd(firmware code) availabel at http://www.broadcom.com/support/communications_processors/downloads.php, I am going through http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html to develop an understanding of FAT file system. I have developed some understanding of the code too from the above link. But still not able to write the full fledge code...missing some design part....Could u guys plz help me to develop an implementation level understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the FAT32 data structures, and viewing the raw sectors with the help of NTdiskviewer utility...I have developed better understanding. Currently I have implemented it partially and open/create functions are working very fine.